# Why does ActiveRecord save String nil record's values to space?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've got the following from my rails console:

```
> u = User.new
=> #<User id:nil, ...
> u.name = nil
=> nil
> u.name
=> nil
> u.save
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   [...]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
=> true
> u.name
=> " "
```

Why the `name` field is set to `' '` after saving the record?

Comment: Which adapter are you using?

Comment: You might have a callback (`before_save`, `before_validation`) that forces the `name` attribute to be a string

Comment: How does your `app/models/user.rb` look like? How does the definition for the `users` table in your `db/schema.rb` look like?

Comment: @FedeBonisconti It's using `postgres` and the field has no default value in DB neither have the requirement to be set to something particular.

You can see my comment to @metahamze's answer to know what is happening and why I've got this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first place I'd look for why this is happening is in the User model to see if there are any [Active Record callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) modifying the data before it gets saved.

It could also be database-level. But in general in any RDBMS there are additional procedures that can be triggered by database commits that can introduce mutations, in ways that can seem unexpected if you don't know where to look.

Comment: Thought the same thing. Probably he's missing first_name and last_name. Something like that.

Comment: @Ursus you were right. Here's what I found in the model:


`self.update_columns(name: "#{first_name} #{last_name}")`

Answer (score 1):

It's highly probable that column does not allow `NULL` values, so your `nil` is being coerced into an empty string to pass validations.

Change your schema to allow `NULL` if that's an issue.

Comment: but that is not even an empty string. That is a single space (seems very odd)

Comment: @engineersmnky Without seeing the model code, this is the best hypothesis I have.